# Building a WAR with unzipped JAR dependencies?

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, war, unpack

I would like to include all my `.class` from a dependency jar into WAR `classes/` directory instead of having a Jar in `lib/` directory.

I have :

```
my-webapp/
  ...
  WEB-INF/
    lib/
      mylib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I would like :

```
my-webapp/
  ...
  WEB-INF/
    classes/
      mylib-1.0-SNAPSHOT (all **.class**)
```

I also see *maven-dependency-plugin* but it requires that my jar is installed into local or remote repository. But `mylib-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is compiled juste before my WAR and if If I call `mvn package`, It's fail !

So, how to unpack my jar dependency into war classes ? (like `maven-shade-plugin` for Jar)

Comment: What is the point of having classes instead jar in your Web application?

Comment: Because Jar contains commons classes of my services, and this webapp contains specific classes. I have multiple webapps using same classes, so I have packaged them into a Jar dependency. For no code duplication ! Do you think it's the right way ?

Comment: You may still use the classes from the common jar if it is in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory; everything in `WEB-INF/lib` will end up in the web app's classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to write this in a commnet, but text is too long.

Sorry, I dont get your point. You have multiple webapps that share classes so you have packaged into a JAR those common classes and now you can distribute the jar and avoid code duplication. That is OK. At this point, for a Webapp, there is no difference between having a class in /WEB-INF/classes or in /WEB-INF/lib/ as part of a jar, the webapp can use the classes in both cases.

With Maven, you should have n project. One for your common jar, and then, one for each webapp you have (where you common jar is a dependency). Before build a WAR for one of your webapp, if common classes have changed, you should first install (in your common repository) the jar: `mvn install`. Once jar is installed, you can build your WAR: `mvn war:war`

Comment: Ok, but the problem with this, is when I have some classes that depends another in same package. Separating these classes into Jar for commons classes and *classes folder* for my specifics data is not natural for me. Moreover, my project is actually builded with Ant, changing it for Maven change my deliverable (jar, war, ear) structure... But if there is no *options* to set it, ok.

Comment: If now, you have been requested to work with Maven instead Ant, I suggest what I've wrote above: common jar for common classes and `classes` folder for specific code  (that's our specific source code to its specific webapp application). Maven is not so nice when you try to do something out of conventions, so try to avoid it.